# Using variables in Groovy and Jenkins pipeline build

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline build that needs to obtain the commit id (sha), so from what i can see the only way to get this is by doing the following

```
sh "git rev-parse --long HEAD > .git/commit-id"                        
GIT_COMMIT = readFile('.git/commit-id')
```

I need to use the GIT_COMMIT var within a curl command but am having trouble using it

```
sh '''curl "https://api.github.com/repos/myRepo/myBuild/statuses/${GIT_COMMIT}"}"''' 
sh '''curl "https://api.github.com/repos/myRepo/myBuild/statuses/GIT_COMMIT"}"'''
```

At the moment GIT_COMMIT is not being passed through, it is always blank, but yet if i echo it i get the value back

```
echo GIT_COMMIT
--long
12345678910
```

Can anyone advise on how i achieve what i require please

Thanks

UPDATE

I have tried the following but still no luck

```
sh '''GIT_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse HEAD)'''
sh '''curl "https://api.github.com/repos/myBuild/statuses/$GIT_COMMIT"'''
```

Comment: Side note: `git rev-parse` does not understand `--long`; that's why the file has a line in it that just reads `--long` (`git rev-parse` echos back unknown arguments). It's not a good idea to rely on this though: what happens if a future version of `git rev-parse` acquires a new `--long` flag that *does* do something?

Comment: Yes wondered why that was in the file, so now have just resorted to git rev-parse HEAD which seems to be doing the job.... unless you have any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I know nothing of Groovy, but `git rev-parse HEAD` is a good way to find the raw commit ID for the current commit. Since it looks as though that's what you need, that seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do away with having to write to a file to keep the commit hash you can use `returnStdout: true` on `sh` and pass it directly.

```
GIT_COMMIT = sh script: 'git rev-parse HEAD',  returnStdout: true
sh """curl "https://api.github.com/repos/myBuild/statuses/${GIT_COMMIT}""""
```

Comment: thanks, i dont get a value back though, GIT_COMMIT = ""

Comment: I copied the command inside the script part wrong. Should work now.

Comment: Thanks, it does now assign the commit id to GIT_COMMIT.. for some reason though now i get an error when using it in a script, `illegal characters in url`. would that have anything to do with `returnStdout: true`

Comment: in the end i had to do `GIT_COMMIT = GIT_COMMIT.replaceAll("\\s","")` to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a need for assigning the commit hash to a variable, you can do this in a single line without outputting to a file:

```
sh "curl https://api.github.com/repos/myRepo/myBuild/statuses/\$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
```

Keep in mind that triple quotes are only necessary for multiline strings in Groovy http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_triple_double_quoted_string

Comment: You know that `echo \`command\` ` is literally the same as just `command`, right? Just less efficient because of the multiple I/O manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Variable/expression expansion (interpolation) only works in Groovy for certain types of string literal syntax. The syntax you are using:

```
'''content${interpolation}etc'''
```

is not one of them. Instead replace the triple-single-quotes (`'''`) with triple-double-quotes (`"""`), like this:

```
sh """curl "https://api.github.com/repos/myRepo/myBuild/statuses/${GIT_COMMIT}"}""""
```

**EDIT:** I'm also a bit concerned that there may still be syntax errors in this statement, particularly the extra `}"` at the end. Maybe the following is more like what you really need?:

```
sh """curl "https://api.github.com/repos/myRepo/myBuild/statuses/${GIT_COMMIT}""""
```

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try

Comment: If the individual who voted this answer down would be so kind as to explain the problem with it I would greatly appreciate it.